# SAS proc optmodel: trying to find the optimal cut-off

Tags: sas

I'm new to proc optmodel and would appreciate any help to solve the problem at hand. 
Here's my problem:

My dataset is like below:

```
 data my data;
    input A B C;
cards;
0 240 3
3.4234 253 2
0 258 7
0 272 4
0 318 7
0 248 8
0 260 2
0.2555 305 5
0 314 5
1.7515 235 7
32 234 4
0 301 3
0 293 5
0 302 12
0 234 2
0 258 4
0 289 2
0 287 10
0 313 3
0.7725 240 7
0 268 3
1.4411 286 9
0 234 13
0.0474 318 2
0 315 4
0 292 5
0.4932 272 3
0 288 4
0 268 4
0 284 6
0 270 4
50.9188 293 3
0 272 3
0 284 2
0 307 3
;
run;
```

There are 3 variables(A,B,C) and I want to classify observations into three classes (H,M,L) based on these 3 variables.

For class H, I want to maximize A, minimize B and C;

For class M, I want to median A,B and C;

For class L, I want to minimize A, maximize B and C.

Also, the constrain is that I want to limit the total observations classified into H less than 5%, and total observations classified into M less than 7%.

The final target is finding the cut-off of A,B,C for classifying obs into three different classes.

Since the three classes are equally weighted,so I scaled the vars first and create a risk var where risk =  A+(1-B)+(1-C);

Thanks in advance for any help.

my sas code:

```
proc stdize data=my_data out=my_data1 method=RANGE;
   var A B C;
run;

data new;
  set my_data1;
  risk =  A+(1-B)+(1-C);
run;

proc sort data=new out=range;
  by risk;
run;


proc optmodel;
/* read data */
set CUTOFF;
/* str risk_level {CUTOFF}; */
num a {CUTOFF};
num b {CUTOFF};
num c {CUTOFF};
read data my_data1 into CUTOFF=[_n_] a=A b=B c=C;
impvar risk{p in CUTOFF} = a[p]+(1-b[p])+(1-c[p]);

var indh {CUTOFF} binary;
var indmh {CUTOFF} binary;
var indo {CUTOFF} binary;

con sum{p in CUTOFF} indh[p] le 10;
con sum{p in CUTOFF} indmh[p] le 6;
con sum{p in CUTOFF} indo[p] le 19;
con class{p in CUTOFF}:indh[p]+indmh[p]+indo[p] le 1;

max new = sum{p in CUTOFF}(10*indh[p]+4*indmh[p]+indo[p])*risk[p];

solve;
print a b c risk indh indmh indo new;
quit;
```

So now my problem is how to find the min risk value in each class,Thanks!

Comment: I have problem writing the code that classify obs into classes(H.M.L)

Comment: Can you post the code you're using so others can help troubleshoot?

Comment: I posted my code...I am confused how to classify obs into different classes, thanks in advance!

Comment: Are the 3 classes entirely independent of each other? e.g. if you optimize H, can you reuse those same observations to optimize L?

Comment: yes, the 3 classes entirely independent and also the three variables (A,B,C) are equally weighted.